# Issue with Django Migration - "Table already exists

Tags: python, django

I'm encountering a problem while trying to run migrations in my Django project. When I run python manage.py migrate, I'm getting the following error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'myapp_mymodel' already exists")

This error seems to be related to a table already existing in the database, but I haven't manually created it, and it's not in my migration files. I've tried the following steps:

Checked migration files for any duplicates or errors.
Deleted the database and recreated it.
Verified that there are no stray migration files in the app.

Comment: what database do you use? If you use `SQLite` then maybe you work with wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the record asociated to that table from the  *django_migrations* table:

```bash
$ python manage.py dbshell
```

```
(sql) >> delete * from table django_migrations where app='myapp':
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
migrate --fake
```

Then

```
migrate
```